# eval(input()) :input at most expected at most 1 argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a begginer at python , i recently shifted from python 2.7 to 3.2
in version 2.7

```
int(raw_input("Enter a number :"))
```

works fine to take a numeric input but what i have learnt is that in 3.2 we have to use

```
eval(input("Enter a number :"))
```

instead, but whenever the enter a numeric input it gives me an error "Input expected at most 1 arguments, got 2".although m just entering just an integer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `int(input(...))`.

```
>>> m = int(input("Enter a number: "))
Enter a number: 5
>>> m
5
```

Comment: thanks alot , actually i just realized i was using wrong syntax for the string associated with input command

Answer (score 2):

Nope, in Python 3 you can still use `int`:

```
val = int(input("Enter a number: "))
print(val)
>>> Enter a number: 10
>>> 10
```

Comment: @johnny in python3 there is no `raw_input`.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine with me :

```
m = eval(input("Enter a number :"))
print(m)
```

Output:

```
Enter a number :5  
5
```